# WCF initialization slow vs .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, remoting

I'm trying to migrate a .NEt Remoting app to WCF, right now both services(Remoting and WCF) are living together.
I have one client consuming both of this services at the same time and I noticed that in the very first call to WCF service it takes a little bit longer than the first call to .NET Remoting service.

With .NET Remoting service the first call get response almost immediately.

.NEt Remoting first call response time: less than a second.

WCF first call response time: about 2 seconds.

I know that there is some initialization cost for WCF connection to be opened, but how can I accelerate this WCF channel wakeup time ??

Any hint?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Which binding are you using? `NetTcpBinding`?

Comment: netTcpBinding in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

WCF is doing so much more than remoting. There is a cost for this work. Full stop.

Try calling the WCF service before you need it. Consider adding a `Heartbeat()` or `Init()` method to the service to trigger the startup process. If the startup is completed by the first call, there should not be a delay for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to host in AppFabric then you could use the [Auto-Start Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx) which is specifically designed to get the application initialized before the first client call.

> **Benefits of the Auto-Start Feature**
>
> When you enable the auto-start
>   feature for a service, the service is up and running as soon as the
>   application that it belongs to is started and before the service
>   receives the first WCF message from the client. Therefore, the service
>   processes the first message quickly because it is already initialized.